# Limit of a sum of a combination

Tags: calculus

I would like to show that $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\frac{1}{n-2k}$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. However, I don't know how to approach this (or if it's even true). I would love a hint.

Comment: For $n$ even and $k=n/2$, $1/(n-2k)$ is undefined.

Comment: For $n$ even, the sum is undefined, and for $n$ odd, the sum is identically $0$ (by the symmetry of Pascal's Triangle).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What happens for $k=n-k$?

Comment: (+1) I didn't see this before I posted my comment, but this is exactly what I mean by the symmetry of Pascal's Triangle.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even, there is an infinite addendum (that for which $k=\frac{n}2$).

So your question should be rather if $n=2h+1\to\infty$, $h\in\mathbb N$...

In this case the **hint** is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} = 2^n$$

What happens when you divide some of the addenda? When are they divided by more than $2$? By more than $4$?

Comment: I see.... But I still have trouble understanding how to reach a formal result. I'm not sure how I could consider the $\frac{1}{n-2k}$ inside the sum; I can't seem to figure out how to quantify exactly how much smaller the sum is than $2^n$. Also thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you a way to compute the exact value of the give sum using the binomial theorem. To avoid the undefined cases, assume $n$ is odd. Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^{n-2k-1}=x^{n-1}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^n$$ and now integrate both sides with respect to $x$ (and discard the additional constant appropriately) which will give you $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\dfrac{x^{n-2k}}{n-2k}$$ in RHS. Then evaluate the resulting integrals at $x=1.$